# UPDATE при разном id

Tags: php, sql

имеется следующий запрос:

```
UPDATE data SET value= :value WHERE id = :id
```

**:value - значение нажатой кнопки, :id - id выделенного checkbox**

В данный момент обновляется только 1 запись, а если отметить несколько чекбоксов, то обновляется только последний чекбокс который был выделен, как можно сделать что бы обновлялись все строки, у которых был отмечен чекбокс (количество чекбоксов динамическое) и id у каждого уникальное
Спасибо

Comment: выполнять обновление **в цикле**

Comment: @Ипатьев, можно пример?

Comment: пример чего? цикла? Вы это сейчас серьёзно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update data
set value= ( case
                 when id = :id1 then :value1
                 when id = :id2 then :value2
                 when id = :id3 then :value3
    end )
    where id in (:id1, :id2, :id3);
```

Comment: В данный момент пример для 3 строк, так а они же меняются постоянно, или я немного не понял?

Comment: @ЛысенкоВладимир вы можете сгенерировать запрос для любого количества строк. Просто в примере я три указал.